# V-textarea custom height and width change?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

Is there a way to customize the height and width of textarea?
It's really huge and i need it no bigger than the size of a button and also is there a way to add an icon next to the placeholder?

I tried changing rows to 1 but that doesn't do me much.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MdxprL

```
    <v-flex>
     <v-btn>
     Hello!!
    </v-btn>

     <v-textarea
   placeholder="can it be the size of the button above somehow? Also how can i add an icon after the placeholder end?"
   rows="1">
     </v-textarea>
    </v-flex>
```

Thank you everyone in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `style` to set the width (or a wrapper `div` etc.. with a specific width).. You can also add an icon to the `v-textarea` and get tricky with user input to make it appear as part of the `placeholder` text.. You cannot natively add icons to `placeholder` text due to different fonts..

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/eaXWPB)

Something like this should work:

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    text: ''
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire"> 
    <v-flex>
      <v-btn>
        Hello!!
      </v-btn>
      <v-textarea
       v-model="text"
       style="width:300px;"
       height="100"
       :append-icon="text == '' ? 'person' : ''"
       class="ml-5"
       placeholder="can it be the size of the button above somehow? Also how can i add an icon after the placeholder end?"
      ></v-textarea>
    </v-flex>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yeah this was as far as i could get to. but thank you for a pretty good answer.